# How do I create a simple tree-table within ember.js addon ember-table?

Tags: ember.js, ember-table

I have some basic data currently displayed in a table.  What is the simplest way to group the data by one of those columns?

(The provided tree example seems overloaded with many other unnecessary features.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation for an ember treetable: https://github.com/jadekler/git-ember-treetable. You can see it in action here: http://jeandeklerk.com/showcase/ember_treetable